# Transaction.atomic while overriding save() method in Django model?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, transactions, overriding

I'm overriding default `save()` method in my model and I'm creating a related model instance there:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    parent_folder = None
    if self.parent:
        parent_folder = self.parent.task_folders.all().first()

    folder, created = Folder.objects.get_or_create(
        project=self.project,
        task=self,
        parent=parent_folder,
        defaults={'name': self.name,
                  'project': self.project,
                  'task': self,
                  'creator': self.creator,
                  'parent': parent_folder,
                  'is_root': True
                  })
```

The question is - should I use `transaction.atomic` here? How does it work with `save()` method?

Answer (score 5):

No, you don't need to use **Atomic Transaction** such as **"@transaction.atomic"** or **"with transaction.atomic():"** explicitly for **overrided "save()"** in **Django Model** because **Atomic Transaction** is implicitly used for **overrided "save()"** by default.

Using **PostgreSQL**, I experimented if **Atomic Transaction** is implicitly used for **overrided "save()"** by default or not with the code below. ***"SELECT", "INSERT", "UPDATE" and "DELETE" queries** are run by **"Animal" class code** in **the overrided "save()"** on **"models.py"** as shown below:

```py
# "store/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Animal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        animal = Animal.objects.all() # For "SELECT" query
        print(animal) # Needed to run "SELECT" query

        Animal(name='Dog').save() # For "INSERT" query

        Animal.objects.filter(name="Dog").update(name="Cat") # For "UPDATE" query

        Animal.objects.filter(name="Cat").delete() # For "DELETE" query

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
```

Then, I add a person to run **the overrided "save()"** in **"Person" class** as shown below. *Actually, **the person "John Smith"** is not added because **the overrided "save()"** doesn't have **"super().save(*args, **kwargs)"**:

[image]

Now, between **"BEGIN" and "COMMIT" queries**, **"SELECT", "INSERT", "UPDATE" and "DELETE" queries** are run by **"Animal" class code** in **the overrided "save()"**. So, **Atomic Transaction** is implicitly used for **overrided save()** by default. *These logs below are **the query logs of PostgreSQL**. You can check [**On PostgreSQL, how to log SQL queries with transaction queries such as "BEGIN" and "COMMIT"**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54780698/postgresql-database-log-transaction/73432601#73432601):

[image]

In addition, **at the end of the overrided "save()"**, I add **"super().save(*args, **kwargs)"** which runs **"INSERT" query** as shown below:

```py
# "store/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Animal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        animal = Animal.objects.all() # For "SELECT" query
        print(animal) # Needed to run "SELECT" query

        Animal(name='Dog').save() # For "INSERT" query

        Animal.objects.filter(name="Dog").update(name="Cat") # For "UPDATE" query

        Animal.objects.filter(name="Cat").delete() # For "DELETE" query

        super().save(*args, **kwargs) # For "INSERT" query

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
```

Then, I add a person to run **the overrided "save()"** in **"Person" class** as shown below. *This time, **the person "John Smith"** is added because **the overrided "save()"** has **"super().save(*args, **kwargs)"**:

[image]

Now, **"INSERT" query** is run by **"super().save(*args, **kwargs)"** after **"DELETE" query** between **"BEGIN" and "COMMIT" queries** as shown below:

[image]

Next, **at the beginning of the overrided "save()"**, I add **"super().save(*args, **kwargs)"** which runs **"INSERT" query** as shown below:

```py
# "store/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Animal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super().save(*args, **kwargs) # For "INSERT" query
        
        animal = Animal.objects.all() # For "SELECT" query
        print(animal) # Needed to run "SELECT" query

        Animal(name='Dog').save() # For "INSERT" query

        Animal.objects.filter(name="Dog").update(name="Cat") # For "UPDATE" query

        Animal.objects.filter(name="Cat").delete() # For "DELETE" query

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
```

Then, I add a person to run **the overrided "save()"** in **"Person" class** as shown below. *This time, **the person "John Smith"** is added because **the overrided "save()"** has **"super().save(*args, **kwargs)"**:

[image]

Now, **"INSERT" query** is run by **"super().save(*args, **kwargs)"** before **"SELECT" query** between **"BEGIN" and "COMMIT" queries** as shown below:

[image]

Next, for **the overrided "save()"**, I put **"@transaction.atomic" decorator** as shown below:

```py
# "store/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Animal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    
    @transaction.atomic # Here
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        animal = Animal.objects.all() # For "SELECT" query
        print(animal) # Needed to run "SELECT" query

        Animal(name='Dog').save() # For "INSERT" query

        Animal.objects.filter(name="Dog").update(name="Cat") # For "UPDATE" query

        Animal.objects.filter(name="Cat").delete() # For "DELETE" query

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
```

Or, for **the overrided "save()"**, I put **"with transaction.atomic():"** as shown below:

```py
# "store/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Animal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        with transaction.atomic(): # Here

            animal = Animal.objects.all() # For "SELECT" query
            print(animal) # Needed to run "SELECT" query

            Animal(name='Dog').save() # For "INSERT" query

            Animal.objects.filter(name="Dog").update(name="Cat") # For "UPDATE" query

            Animal.objects.filter(name="Cat").delete() # For "DELETE" query

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
```

Then, I add a person to run **the overrided "save()"** in **"Person" class** as shown below:

[image]

Now, **"SAVEPOINT" and "RELEASE SAVEPOINT" queries** are run by **"@transaction.atomic" decorator** or **"with transaction.atomic():"** after **"BEGIN" query** and after **"DELETE" query** respectively between **"BEGIN" and "COMMIT" queries** as shown below:

[image]

Next, for **the overrided "save()"** as shown below:

```py
# "store/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Animal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        animal = Animal.objects.all() # For "SELECT" query
        print(animal) # Needed to run "SELECT" query

        Animal(name='Dog').save() # For "INSERT" query

        Animal.objects.filter(name="Dog").update(name="Cat") # For "UPDATE" query

        Animal.objects.filter(name="Cat").delete() # For "DELETE" query

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
```

I put **'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True** to **my PostgreSQL settings** in **"settings.py"**:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

DATABASES = {
    'default':{
        'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME':'postgres',
        'USER':'postgres',
        'PASSWORD':'admin',
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT':'5432',
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True, # Here
    }
}
```

Then, I add a person to run **the overrided "save()"** in **"Person" class** as shown below:

[image]

Now, **"SAVEPOINT" and "RELEASE SAVEPOINT" queries** are run by **'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True** before **"SELECT" query run by "Animal" class code** and before **"COMMIT" query** respectively and **2 "SELECT" queries in blue** are added between **"BEGIN" and "COMMIT" queries** as shown below:

[image]

Next, for **the overrided "save()"**, I put both **"@transaction.atomic" decorator** and **"with transaction.atomic():"** as shown below:

```py
# "store/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Animal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    
    @transaction.atomic # Here
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        with transaction.atomic(): # Here

            animal = Animal.objects.all() # For "SELECT" query
            print(animal) # Needed to run "SELECT" query

            Animal(name='Dog').save() # For "INSERT" query

            Animal.objects.filter(name="Dog").update(name="Cat") # For "UPDATE" query

            Animal.objects.filter(name="Cat").delete() # For "DELETE" query

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
```

And, I also put **'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True** to **my PostgreSQL settings** in **"settings.py"** as shown below:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

DATABASES = {
    'default':{
        'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME':'postgres',
        'USER':'postgres',
        'PASSWORD':'admin',
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT':'5432',
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True, # Here
    }
}
```

Then, I add a person to run **the overrided "save()"** in **"Person" class** as shown below:

[image]

Now, between **"BEGIN" and "COMMIT" queries**, **3 "SAVEPOINT" and 3 "RELEASE SAVEPOINT" queries** are run by **"@transaction.atomic" decorator**, **"with transaction.atomic():"** and **'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True** and **2 "SELECT" queries in blue** are added as shown below:

[image]

In addition again, using **PostgreSQL**, I also experimented if **Atomic Transaction** is implicitly used for **Views** by default or not with the code below. ***"SELECT", "INSERT", "UPDATE" and "DELETE" queries** are run by **"Animal" class code** in **"test()" view** on **"views.py"** as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Animal

def test(request):

    animal = Animal.objects.all() # For "SELECT" query
    print(animal) # Needed to run "SELECT" query

    Animal(name='Dog').save() # For "INSERT" query

    Animal.objects.filter(name="Dog").update(name="Cat") # For "UPDATE" query

    Animal.objects.filter(name="Cat").delete() # For "DELETE" 

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

And, this is **"urls.py"** below:

```py
# "store/urls.py"

from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "store"

urlpatterns = [
    path('test/', views.test, name="test"),
]
```

Then, I open **the url "http://localhost:8000/store/test/"** to run **"test" view** as shown below:

[image]

Now, between **"BEGIN" and "COMMIT" queries**, **only "DELETE" query** is run by **"Animal" class code** in **"test()"** view., So, **Atomic Transaction** is not implicitly used for **Views** by default. *These logs below are **the query logs of PostgreSQL**:

[image]

Next, for **"test()" view**, I put **"@transaction.atomic" decorator** as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Animal

@transaction.atomic # Here
def test(request):
    
    animal = Animal.objects.all() # For "SELECT" query
    print(animal) # Needed to run "SELECT" query

    Animal(name='Dog').save() # For "INSERT" query

    Animal.objects.filter(name="Dog").update(name="Cat") # For "UPDATE" query

    Animal.objects.filter(name="Cat").delete() # For "DELETE" 

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Or, for **"test()" view**, I put **"with transaction.atomic():"** as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Animal

def test(request):

    with transaction.atomic(): # Here
    
        animal = Animal.objects.all() # For "SELECT" query
        print(animal) # Needed to run "SELECT" query

        Animal(name='Dog').save() # For "INSERT" query

        Animal.objects.filter(name="Dog").update(name="Cat") # For "UPDATE" query

        Animal.objects.filter(name="Cat").delete() # For "DELETE" 

        return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Or, for **"test()" view**, I put **'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True** to **my PostgreSQL settings** in **"settings.py"** as shown below:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

DATABASES = {
    'default':{
        'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME':'postgres',
        'USER':'postgres',
        'PASSWORD':'admin',
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT':'5432',
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True, # Here
    }
}
```

Then, I open **the url "http://localhost:8000/store/test/"** to run **"test" view** as shown below:

[image]

Now, between **"BEGIN" and "COMMIT" queries**, **"SELECT", "INSERT", "UPDATE" and "DELETE" queries** are run by **"Animal" class code** in **"test()" view**. So now, **Atomic Transaction** works:

[image]

Next, for **"test()" view**, I put both **"@transaction.atomic" decorator** and **"with transaction.atomic():"** as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Animal

@transaction.atomic # Here
def test(request):
    
    with transaction.atomic(): # Here
        
        animal = Animal.objects.all() # For "SELECT" query
        print(animal) # Needed to run "SELECT" query

        Animal(name='Dog').save() # For "INSERT" query

        Animal.objects.filter(name="Dog").update(name="Cat") # For "UPDATE" query

        Animal.objects.filter(name="Cat").delete() # For "DELETE" 

        return HttpResponse("Test")
```

And, I also put **'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True** to **my PostgreSQL settings** in **"settings.py"** as shown below:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

DATABASES = {
    'default':{
        'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME':'postgres',
        'USER':'postgres',
        'PASSWORD':'admin',
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT':'5432',
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True, # Here
    }
}
```

Then, I open **the url "http://localhost:8000/store/test/"** to run **"test" view** as shown below:

[image]

Now, between **"BEGIN" and "COMMIT" queries**, **2 "SAVEPOINT" and 2 "RELEASE SAVEPOINT" queries** are run as shown below:

[image]